# Variable (int pointer to int pointers to int ,(NxN array of int), crashes once some inputs are stored?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, scanf

The purpose of this application is to make an NxN variable/user defined array using multi-pointers
The entire "array" (figure of speech) is filled entirely , 
Then a function adds all numbers in line and finds the sum of each line storing in it in a new "array" , which is being returned (I mean the pointer to it) 
You **can't** possibly return an **ENTIRE ARRAY** right?
I know `scanf()` is evil (hehe) i will change it to `fgets()` with `atoi()` if thats the problem!
After a few valid inputs it crashes!!!
PS **33 E:\ask1.c [Warning] assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int* linesum(int **ar);

main()
{
    int n,i,j,*temp,SIZE;   
    printf("Input Array Dimensions NxN ");
    scanf(" %d",&SIZE);
    int **Table=(int**)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(int*));   
    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++) 
        *(Table+i)=(int*)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(int));  

    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
        for(j=0;j<SIZE;j++){        
           printf("Input int of %d row %d column ",i,j);
           scanf(" %d",*(Table+i*SIZE+j));          
    }
    temp=linesum(Table,SIZE);
    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
       printf("Sum of line %d is %d",i,*(temp+i));
    return 0;
}

int* linesum(int **ar,int N)
{
    int i,j,lsum=0;
    int *new=malloc(N*sizeof(int)); 
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(j=0;j<N;i++)
            lsum+=*(ar+i*N+j);
        *(new+i)=lsum;
    }
    return (new);       
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write something like `Table+i*SIZE+j` you are assuming that your "2-dimensional array" is stored contiguously in memory. **It is not.** You did not allocate an array to hold N*M elements. You created N arrays to hold M elements each. Each of these N arrays has a different (and almost certainly non-contiguous) start address.

The proper way to index this array-of-arrays is `Table[i][j]`.

To index it without using `[]` (as requested by OP in comments below) you can write `*(*(Table + i) + j)`. I do not recommend this as it is much less readable than `Table[i][j]`.

Comment: Is there a way to allocate the memory contiguously with pointers?
I am not allowed to use array indexing (and I would not because I learn pointers now :D)

Comment: And by the way besides pointer arithmetic and indexing is there a way to access those non-memory-continuous elements ?

Comment: @niCk You can also write `*(*(Table + i) + j)` but honestly that is very unreadable IMO. To allocate a single NxM array just say `malloc(SIZE*SIZE*sizeof(int))` and have `Table` be an `int*` instead of `int**`; you can then access it the way you do in your OP.

Comment: I did *(*(Table + i) + j) at my scanf() above, now it accepts all inputs for all cells and then crashes. (at least now it takes all values)

Comment: @niCk For `scanf()` you want to pass the address of the cell, not the value, so remove the leading `*`: `sscanf("%d", (*(Table + i) + j))`

Comment: @niCk Also your `linesum()` function is broken; it is not allocating enough space in `new`. Note that `sizeof(ar)` here is equivalent to `sizeof(int**)` which returns the size of a pointer, probably 4 (if 32 bit machine) or 8 (64 bit machine). You probably want to use `SIZE` here instead.

Comment: Removing the leading * yet the problem persists, scanf() is to be ripped out of the source ASAP

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
scanf(" %d",*(Table+i*SIZE+j));
```

To:

```
scanf(" %d",&Table[i][j]);
```

Your main problem, however, is the use of `sizeof(ar)`.

You cannot get the real array length using `sizeof` on a pointer to the array.

I'm afraid you're gonna have to find a better way (just send `SIZE` from the calling function).

Also, you need to call `free(temp)` after printing the results.

Finally, don't use `new`. It's a reserved word in C++, and besides the fact that it's confusing, if you ever port this code to C++, it will not compile.

Comment: Its a great idea but besides pointer arithmetic and indexing is there another way to access those non-memory-continuous elements ?

Comment: Good to know its will run only in C , since program exits why should I deallocate memory (I mean its not memory leak if its run-once then exit after 10 seconds right?)

Comment: No. Memory allocated dynamically (during runtime), is not a part of the memory where your program resides (which includes only the code-section of your program (functions), the data-section of your program (global and static variables), and the stack of your program (non-static local variables)). So when your program exits, this memory is not deallocated.

Comment: I should also free(new) despite the local scope but I think temp will indirectly free(this)

Comment: DO NOT free the address pointed by variable `new` in function `linesum`. You are using this address in function `main` and should free it only afterwards.